# How to speed up wifi repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I've setup an Asus RT-N12 router as a wifi repeater. But It's about 30% slower than wired speeds or other wifi speed.

```
 Internet  -----Primary WifiRouter------N12 Router (repeater)---- Win 10 Desktop
                               |------Win 10 Laptop
```

Measurements

- Windows 10 Laptop download speed: **110Mbps**
- Windows 10 Desktop wired download speed **110 Mbps**
- Windows 10 Desktop wireless via N12 Router:  **80 Mbps**

I read somewhere that the Repeater router may be using the same channel for both ends of it's repeated link (upstream and downstream)

Is there any way to speed this up and get close to the source Internet speedH/

Answer (score 0):

> How to speed up wifi repeater?

Wireless repeater speeds are slower because the speed is half (up and down) and gets worse the farther away.

[Wireless Repeater speeds](https://www.screenbeam.com/wifihelp/wifibooster/wifi-extenders-beat-wifi-repeaters-every-time/#:%7E:text=The%20further%20away%20the%20WiFi,leads%20to%20slower%20connection%20speeds.)

> The further away the WiFi repeater is from the router, the weaker the
> signal will be.
>
> **A WiFi repeater connects to a router and wireless devices on the same
> frequency. This means that your wireless devices will only get half of
> the bandwidth available.** Less bandwidth leads to slower connection
> speeds.

So what you see is entirely normal.

Consider a wireless Extender (different gear) instead.